# Why there is no smartctl tool in ESXi 5.x?

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi

I'm using some kind of Whitebox and my hardware drives are not recognized under Configuration -> Health Status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ESXi hardware status is monitored using CIM

> VMware's CIM Provider Program is open to qualified OEMs and IHVs
>   interested in developing CIM providers for VMware ESX. CIM Provider
>   partners have access to the VMware Workbench CIM Provider Development
>   Kit (CIM PDK) plugin, including a build environment, test framework,
>   and other tools. Partners interact with VMware's R&D engineers to
>   create and test CIM providers and to influence future enhancements to
>   VMware's CIM infrastructure.

[CIM Providers](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/vcl/cimprovider.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're using "white box" hardware.

Server-class systems provide hooks for VMWare monitoring/health status.